# Why ln -s creates relative broken links?

Tags: symlink, ln

I have an issue with `ln -s` on Ubuntu 14.04, while using it in the following scenario:

```
$ cd ~/programming/tmux/
$ ln -s tmux ~/bin/tmux
$ ls -l ~/bin/tmux
lrwxrwxrwx 1 USER USER 4 sie 31 11:02 /home/USER/bin/tmux -> tmux
```

Why is it like so? When I create it giving the absolute path everything works fine:

```
$ ln -s ~/programming/tmux/tmux ~/bin/tmux
$ ls -l ~/bin/tmux
lrwxrwxrwx 1 USER USER 4 sie 31 11:02 /home/USER/bin/tmux -> ~/programming/tmux/tmux
```

Comment: The shell expands `~` so `ln` never sees `~`. And if it did, it wouldn't be able to make sense of it and it would fail with a file not found error. You can see this if you quote your link, ala '~/bin/tmux'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you write

```
ln -s VALUE link_name
```

it creates a symbolic link with value `VALUE`. This is what you got. If you want to create a relative link, it is best to cd to the directory where you want to put the link:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s ../programming/tmux/tmux .
```

Shell completion will help you.

Comment: You can also use `-r` flag. It will calculate link's value relative to its final destination, not your current working directory.

Comment: @AkaZecik Yes, but the `-r` flag is a GNU extension, thus not available everywhere.